# Add New Column In Each Object Inside An Array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, mongodb-compass, mongo-collection

Please refer to the attached image.

Questions -
I have to add one column(column name will be Temp) with value "Hello" inside each object (0,1,2) inside "Products" Array.
No of object will not be 3 for each record.
Please help me out with this.

[image]

Comment: It is best to add example document in text/json format and expected output to be easier for auditory to play with your data and provide you good answer ...

Comment: _"No of object will not be 3 for each record"_  What does this mean?  As @R2D2 commented, an example of desired outcome would be helpful.

Comment: Do you mean something like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BZqyhiTQkET)?